# Get data attr form button with JQuery and display value in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

I open a form in a foreach loop which calls a bootstrap modal to appear for each item in the loop for confirmation before deleting. I want the category name to display in the modal.

Form:

```
          <table class='table table-striped' data-form="deleteForm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th width="50px"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{ route('categories.show', $category->id) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        {!! Form::model($category, ['method' => 'delete', 'route' => ['categories.destroy', $category->id], 'class' =>'form-inline form-delete']) !!}
          {!! Form::hidden('id', $category->id) !!}
          {!! Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger', 'name' => 'delete_modal', 'data-title'=>"$category->name"]) !!}
          {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="delete-btn">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
    $('table[data-form="deleteForm"]').on('click', '.form-delete', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form=$(this);
    $('#confirm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $("button[name='delete_modal']")
                var recipient = button.data('title') // Extract info from data-* attributes
                var modal = $(this)
                modal.find('.modal-title').text('Delete Category: ' + recipient)
            });
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
            .on('click', '#delete-btn', function(){
                    $form.submit();
            });
    });
```

currently the modal only displays the first item in the for each loop because

> var button = $("button[name='delete_modal']")

doesn't identify the category selected only the first item in the list. How can i get jquery to identify the data-title value for the button just clicked?

Comment: try with `button.attr('data-title')`

Comment: console.log($(this)) should give the details of current button clicked...is the category name in the log ?

Comment: button.attr('data-title') gives me attr is undefined

Comment: console.log($(this) gives me [div#confirm.modal.fade]

Comment: @RohitasBehera i think im being an idiot here.... it gives me [form#[object HTMLInputElement].form-inline.form-delete] which then contains the button as "button.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger"... how do i reference that in jquery?

Comment: in the   **{!! Form::button('<**   part you gotta give bind same data to the modal..like ID or something...from there whenver the delete is clicked we can retrieve the data